# mocking getResourceClass of ResourceInfo

Tags: java, generics, jax-rs, mockito

I am trying to mock the `getResourceClass` of `javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo`. So what i have done is:

```
ResourceInfo resourceInfo = mock(ResourceInfo.class);
```

Now when i am trying below:

```
when(resourceInfo.getResourceClass()).thenReturn(Class.forName("com.p.q.ClassName"));
```

It throws the below compilation error:

```
The method thenReturn(Class<capture#1-of ?>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Class<capture#1-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ?>)
```

Can anybody help me resolving this. Thanks.

Comment: how about `when(resourceInfo.getResourceClass()).thenReturn(ClassName.class));`?

Comment: @almasshaikh Does not work. Same error.

Comment: @almasshaikh Nope. Why is it to be that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a big Mockito user, so I can't really explain why it doesn't work. But after a little playing around, I found this works

```
ResourceInfo resourceInfo = Mockito.mock(ResourceInfo.class); 
Mockito.doReturn(YouResourceClass.class).when(resourceInfo).getResourceClass();
```

Another option

```
Mockito.<Class<?>>when(resourceInfo.getResourceClass()).thenReturn(YourResource.class);
```